# compute measurement points in a circle

Tags: math, geometry

If there are n (e.g. 100) measurement points on a circle:
Now I try to compute potential offsets.
There is an expected value and a measured value. Expected value - measured value = offset. 
But in a circle with 100 measurement points,
20 to 25 has the same offset as 97 to 2.

What is the known formula that goes like this:
Expected value [1] - Measured value [99] = offset[2]?

[Edit by Spektre (moved from invalid "answer")]

Circumference! Circle. You can set `n` points on that. In [mm] in [cm] ... And eg. point `2` is `2 cm` apart from `4` and `22` is `2` apart from `24`. Easy. But `99` is also `2 cm` apart from `1`.

Comment: I do not at all understand what you are asking. What is a "measurement point," what is a "measurement process," is this a stochastic process so there is a mathematical "expectation," what do you mean by "it's the same difference," and just what do you want the formula for? Please add much more explanation.

Comment: I understood nothing. Could you reformulate question?

Answer (score 2):

Minimal circular distance for circle length n and positions a and b is

```
 dist = Min((a - b + n) % n, (b - a + n) % n)
```

Variant:

```
dist = Abs(a - b)
if dist > n/2
   dist = n - dist
```